# Keeping a user logged in with a session

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, pdo, hash

I am having an issue trying to figure out how I can keep a user logged in by hitting a 'Remember Me' checkbox. The system I have in place inserts the user's id and hash into a database called `users_session` once the 'Remember Me' checkbox is checked and the user successfully logs in.

Now the issue I am having is checking to see if the cookie that stores the hash is the same hash/user_id that will allow the user to automatically log in. The code below labelled login code, you can see where I have tried checking if the hash matches, but it is throwing this error `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in` for this line, `if($this->data()->password === Cookie::get($cookieName)){`.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong that I cannot get the user to stay logged in?

```
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => ''
    ),
    'remember' => array(
        'cookie_name' => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user',
        'token_name' => 'token'
        )
    );

    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    });

    require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';

    if(Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name')) && !Session::exists(Config::get('session/session_name'))) {
        $hash = Cookie::get(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
        $hashCheck = DB::getInstance()->get('users_session', array('hash', '=', $hash));

        if($hashCheck->count()) {
            $user = new User($hashCheck->first()->user_id);
            $user->login();
        }
    }
```

Code that creates the login/storing cooking

```
if(Input::exists()) { 

if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) { 

$validate = new Validate(); 
$validation = $validate->check($_POST, array( 
    'username' => array('required' => true), 
    'password' => array('required' => true) 
)); 

if($validation->passed()) { 
$user = new User();
$cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name'); //added

if(Cookie::exists($cookieName)) {  //added *********
if($this->data()->password === Cookie::get($cookieName)){  //added
echo $logged = '<span class="signinpanel">' . "You've been automatically logged in." . '</span>'; //added
}
else {
echo $logged = '<span class="signinpanel">' . "You could not be automatically logged in." . '</span>'; **strong text**
Cookie::delete($cookieName); //added
}
} 
else { 

$remember = (Input::get('remember') === 'on') ? true : false; 
$login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'), $remember); 

}
if($login) { 
Redirect::to('/account/home'); 
} else { 
echo $tryagain = '<span class="signinpanel">' . "The information you entered did not match our records." . '</span>'; 
} 

} else { 
foreach($validation->errors() as $error) { 
echo $error, '<br>'; 
} 
} 
} 
}
```

Form

```
<form name="Sign In" action="" method="POST" autocomplete="on" accept-charset= "utf-8">
        <div class="field"> 
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="on" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" required>
        </div>  
        <div class="field"> 
            <label for="remember">
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In"> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use $this->data() from outside of a class.

Comment: What can I use then.

Comment: Which class contains the data() method?
Perhaps you're looking for:
$user->password
instead of 
$this->data()->password
?

Comment: My user class. code: `public function data() {
  return $this->_data;
 }`

Comment: It depends what it the _data inside user. Array or another object?

Comment: Well nothing inside of my cookie class is an array, so I am assuming an object.

Comment: I can see only 2 options here. If attribute $_data inside User class is an array, then try `$user->data()['password']`. If $_data is an object, then try `$user->data()->password`. Anyway, you shouldn't store password in cookies.

Comment: I received these errors: `You could not be automatically logged in.
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /register_success.php:25) in/classes/Cookie.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: login in /register_success.php on line 35`

Comment: Line 13 in my cookie class is `if(setcookie($name, $value, time() + $expiry, '/')) {`

Comment: You can't call `Cookie::delete($cookieName);` nor `setcookie()` after `echo`.

Comment: Ok took the `Cookie::delete` out. Now it is throwing this error: `Notice: Undefined variable: login in /register_success.php on line 35` for this line `if($login) { `

Comment: I don't get why `$login` is undefined. It is defined right above it and worked before I added this cookie code.